# Yii2 Dynamically render GridView

Tags: gridview, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a table/model "seminar" (Trainings) and a table/model "category".
They are connected through the field "seminar.category_id" so e.g. that I can use seminar->category->name. That all works.

Now I want to render a GridView-widget for each category, containing the corresponding seminars.

**1)** Should I use multiple GridViews or is there a better way
(I need no filtering, etc.)

**2)** If answer of 1) is yes GridView, how should I implement it?

1. put the code in a widget and call through foreach
2. put the code in a view and call through foreach
3. put the code in a view and call through ListView
4. ...

Sorry for the short question, if necessary I can post more details, but it's more a conceptual question.

---

**UPDATE - solution:**

The answer of Hesam pointed me in the right direction. Since I have to modified the answer I will post my solution here.

**Note:** I used ActiveDataProvider

**SeminarController/actionIndex:**

```
$categories = Category::find()->where(['Status'=>Category::STATUS_ACTIVE])->All();
$dataProviders = [];

foreach ($categories as $category) {

        $dataProviders[] = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $category->getSeminars(),
        ]);
}

return $this->render('index', compact('dataProviders'));
```

Struggled with getting the views to show - dont't work with:

```
<?php foreach(...){ $this->render()}... ?>
```

**view/seminar/index.php:**

```
<?php
foreach ($dataProviders as $dataProvider) {
?>
<?=
    $this->render('_categoryRow', [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
?>
<?php } ?>
```

**/view/seminar/_categoryRow.php:**

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
...
```

**Additional tips:**

1. Getting the current category name from $dataProvider ("name" is a column of "category")

   $dataProvider->query->primaryModel->name
2. Getting the current count of seminars from $dataProvider

   $dataProvider->getCount()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to use multiple data providers with multiple widgets.
Consider we have this code in our action:

```
    $categories = Category::find()->All();
    $dataProviders = [];

    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $dataProviders[] = new ArrayDataProvider([
            'allModels' => $category->seminars,
            'sort' =>['attributes' => ['id'],], // Here you can choose your custom attributes for sorting
            'pagination' => ['pageSize' => 100]
        ]);
    }

    return $this->render('test', compact('dataProviders'));
```

By looping through `$dataProviders` array in view, we can show all categories with their child seminars:

```
    foreach ($dataProviders as $dataProvider) {

    echo GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,

        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'foo',
            'bar',
            'created_at:relativeTime',
            'updated_at:relativeTime',
        ],

    ]) ;

}
```

Hope it can help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it pointed me in the right direction. I have updated my answer to show my concrete solution (I used ActiveDataProvider and a  subview)

Comment: It is good to help you found a proper solution. Using a subview is a more clear way of doing this job, by the way , Active Data Provider will bring you more power of maintainig data.